# Scheme Rotate Function

Tags: list, rotation, scheme

I have to write a function that rotates a list n times. A rotation consists of placing an element from the front to the end of the list. I'm completely lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A basic implementation would be

```
(define (rotate lst n)
  (cond
    [(< n 0) 
     (error "n is negative")]
    [(or (= n 0) (null? lst)) 
     lst]
    [else 
     (rotate (append (cdr lst) (list (car lst))) 
             (- n 1))]))
```

so

```
(rotate '(a b c d e) 3)
=> '(d e a b c)

(rotate '(a b c) 5)
=> '(c a b)
```

As an improvement you should factor out the tests `(< n 0)` and `(null? lst)` because these need only be done once.

Comment: My solution approach is actually shorter, clearer to read, and doesn't have the same computational pitfalls. Still, I avoided posting an actual code solution because I wanted the OP to actually _think_ about the solution rather than just cutting-and-pasting, but I may have to reconsider, in the name of making my answer more likely to be accepted.

Comment: I would also consider my solution truer to functional programming: it's built from very small, composeable, general-purpose functions. `take`, `drop`, and `append` are standard functions in any functional programming toolkit (as are `map` and `fold`, though those are not used in this problem). I would far prefer to use these components than writing a manual loop. Again, not trying to be offensive, just giving my view on code quality. (At work, we have mandatory code reviews, so I have done a lot of them, and have a certain review style I'm accustomed to. I'm sorry you find my style offensive.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young the answer did say it's a "basic" implementation. The OP is just beginning to learn this stuff. This answer shows the localized approach to problem solving (aka recursion), the other creates the end result explicitly. Great exposition! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use (or implement yourself, if this is for a course and your assignment requires you to implement everything by hand) `take`, `drop`, and `append`.

- `(take lst n)` returns the first `n` elements of `lst`. For example, `(take '(1 2 3 4 5) 3)` returns `(1 2 3)`.
- `(drop lst n)` returns everything after the first `n` elements of `lst`. For example, `(drop '(1 2 3 4 5) 3)` returns `(4 5)`.
- `(append lst1 lst2)` returns a list that contains all the elements of `lst1`, followed by all the elements of `lst2`. For example, `(append '(4 5) '(1 2 3))` returns `(4 5 1 2 3)`.

Once you have these functions at hand, implementing a rotation function is trivial:

```
(define (rotate lst n)
  (let ((n (modulo n (length lst))))
    (append (drop lst n) (take lst n))))
```

Comment: What about `(rotate '(a b c) 5)` ?

Comment: @uselpa Use `modulo` and `length`. :-)